# Run Automation Scripts after Deployment on Tomcat Server using Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, selenium, jenkins

I've deployed a servlet based web application(War file) in Tomcat server using Jankins and Maven. Now I want to run some selenium automation scripts on same application, Can it be achieved by Jenkins.
Its like Deploy web application on Sever and once deployment is successful run automation scripts using jenkins..

Please Help..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although we are here to help each other, it's expected that you should at least try something on your own first. If that doesn't work, the next assumption is that you should Google it to check whether the answer is available. Even if that doesn't provide anything useful, then you should post your query. Please check this: `http://bit.ly/1nwXMHs`

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways :

1) Add post build step to your current task and run the scripts there.

2) Add another task ex. "app-automation-scripts" that runs every time that your current task is builded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, 
you can add maven plugin to jenkins, (installed by default most of times) 
then declare your project as war in pom.xml
then add a post processing "maven" to your maven build config and configure it with options "war:war"
-- options you can add for a maven build is: clean install build and etc. war option is for creating war files.

Or:

simply run a bash command using your jenkins build configuration.

Former needs installation of maven plug-in and configuring it,
Later needs configuring your maven to be run on the jenkins server by user named "jenkins".